# meaning of multiple instances sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL and to SQL server and I am using the [book](http://techbus.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9780735670013) to build my knowledge. During early parts of the book, the author has below para. I am confused with the sentence in ***bold and italics*** below.

What is the purpose behind running multiple instances of SQL server on a given server? It seems that SQL server is a very costly software, in such case isn't installing multiple instances a costly task?

> The Database Engine sits at the core of the SQL Server components. The engine operates as a service on a machine, which is often referred to as an instance of SQL Server. ***You can run multiple instances of SQL Server on a given server.*** When you connect to SQL Server, the instance is the target of the connection. Once an application is connected, it sends Transact-SQL (T-SQL) statements to the instance. The instance in return sends data back to the client. Within the connection is a security layer that validates access to the data as specified by the database administrators (DBAs). The Database Engine enables you to leverage the full capabilities of all of the other components, such as accessing, storing, and securing the data..

Comment: what is the purpose behind doing so? any special benefit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to run **various versions** of SQL Server, e.g. 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012 simultaneously in parallel on a given machine. If you're e.g. a consultant and your clients use different versions of SQL Server, and you need to be able to get a backup from them, do some work, and send the database back, you have to use the same version as your client does. Backups aren't backwards-compatible, e.g. if your customer uses 2005, you **can** restore his 2005 backup onto your 2012 server, but you **CANNOT** return the data back to the client (since the backups are **NOT** backwards compatible - you **cannot** restore a 2012 backup on a 2005 server).

Or you might want to run separate instances for e.g. development and testing on the same physical server machine in separate instances (that are quite well isolated from one another). It's a great way to separate two (or more) "worlds" (environments) of SQL Server from one another; you might have all the same databases - but once in the "Development" context (for your dev team, work in progress), and a second time for your Quality Assurance or Testing team. If you have two totally separate instances, it's like having two (or more) servers living on one machine.

Multiple **instances** of SQL Server on a single physical machine are a great way to have separate environments - both based on the versions (and editions) of SQL Server you might need to support, but also in terms of the use of the instances - development vs. testing vs. demo vs. whatever-else-you-might-have.

Instances are very well protected from one another and don't interfere with each other - each has their own databases, logins, security, etc.